# Django Looping Through Business Hours

Tags: python, html, django

This is my code for displaying Restaurant Business Hours:

```
<dl>
  {% for hours in restaurant.businesshours.all %}
   <dt>{{ hours.dayofweek.name }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ hours.hourstype.name }} {{ hours.opentime.name }} - {{ hours.closetime.name }}</dd>
  {% endfor %}
 </dl>
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
Monday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Tuesday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Wednesday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Thursday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Friday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Saturday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Sunday
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Sunday
Lunch 11:30 a.m. - 3 p.m.
Monday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Tuesday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Wednesday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Thursday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Friday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Saturday
Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
```

My goal is to have it grouped by day of the week so the output is something like this:

```
Monday
-Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m. 
-Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Tuesday
-Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m. 
-Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
Wednesday
-Lunch 11 a.m. - 2:30 p.m. 
-Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 10 p.m.
...
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** (models added)

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
businesshours = models.ManyToManyField('Hours', null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurants")
class Meta:
    db_table = 'restaurant'

class Dayofweek(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='dayofweek')
class Meta:
    db_table = 'dayofweek'

class Hours(models.Model): 
dayofweek = models.ForeignKey('Dayofweek', null=True, blank=True, related_name="hours")
hourstype = models.ForeignKey('Hourstype', null=True, blank=True, related_name="hours")
opentime = models.ForeignKey('Timeslot', null=True, blank=True, related_name="hours_opentime")
closetime = models.ForeignKey('Timeslot', null=True, blank=True, related_name="hours_closetime")
class Meta:
    db_table = 'hours'

class Hourstype(models.Model): #Lunch, Dinner etc.
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='hourstype')
class Meta:
    db_table = 'hourstype'

class Timeslot(models.Model): #Each slot is every 15min starting at 5am
name = models.TimeField(db_column='timeslot')
class Meta:
    db_table = 'timeslot'
```

Comment: Hard to give you insight unless we see the model code for the thing you are iterating over!

Comment: I have added Models for the Business Hours. Thanks for looking and for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for the `regroup` tag. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup restaurant.businesshours.all by dayofweek as hours_list %}
<dl>
    {% for hours in hours_list %}
        <dt>{{ hours.grouper.name }}</dt>
        {% for item in hours.list  %}
            <dd>{{ item.hourstype.name }} {{ item.opentime.name }} - {{ item.closetime.name }}</dd>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

EDIT: With the way the related models are configrured. It'd probably be easier to create a dictionary in the view code by looping through your queryset and providing the template with  something similar to this:

```
restaurant_hours = {
    "Monday": [
        {"type": "Breakfast", "hours": "9 a.m. - 12 p.m."},
        {"type": "Lunch", "hours": "12 p.m. - 3 p.m."}
    ]
    ...
}
```

Without being able to test it, this is how I imagine forming the output would probably look:

```
restaurant_hours = dict()

for hours in restaurant.businesshours.all():
    day = hours.dayofweek.name
    if restaurant_hours.get(day):
        restaurant_hours[day].append({"type": hours.hourstype.name, "hours": hours.opentime.name + " - " + hours.closetime.name})
    else:
        restaurant_hours[day] = [{"type": hours.hourstype.name, "hours": hours.opentime.name + " - " + hours.closetime.name}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I run it I get this: `Dayofweek object
Brunch 10:30 a.m. - 2 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 9 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 9 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Lunch 11:45 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Lunch 11:45 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Lunch 11:45 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Lunch 11:45 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Lunch 11:45 a.m. - 2:30 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 9 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 9 p.m.
Dayofweek object
Dinner 5:30 p.m. - 9 p.m.
Dayofweek object
....

Comment: Oh yeah. dayofweek is an object. so instead of hours.grouper it'd be hours.grouper.name. However, this would require a another regroup on a seperate related model. It might be easier to organize everything into a dictionary in the view.

Comment: Thanks!, seems like it is only working partially as some values are grouped and some others are not. Any hints on the "dictionary"?

Comment: The dictionary might be hard to put together but you can give it a shot with a few for loops. You basically just need a `restaurant_hours = []` and loop through the queryset to append values. If this were my project, I might take a step back and reevaluate and try to simplify the relations. For example, do you really need a model just to hold the day of the week? You could use a CharField with a Choice attribute to gain some simplicity there.